# How can I do scanf() to the elements of dynamic 2D array in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I wrote this piece of code to create a 2D dynamic array:

```
int i = 0; 

int row = 3, col = 2; 

p = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));

for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
    p[i] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));
```

assuming `row = 3`, `col = 2`.

How can I do `scanf()` to the elements?

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over all elements in the matrix? Do you know how to get a pointer to a specific element in an array (using the address-of operator `&`)? Then you really know all you need to know.

Comment: By the way, please do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code you show, it's not correct (thing about the loop, where you loop over the *rows*).

Comment: What should happen if the user entered input inadvertently contains non-numeric text like `"123 xyz 789"`?

Comment: The allocation code is incorrect: it should be `for (i = 0; i < row; i++)`